# How to use readlineSync on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying out readlineSync to get user input (saw it was the best option to get user input). But then it doesn't output to the console. And it breaks out of node as soon as its done running. Help me out.

```
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
var firstName = readlineSync.question("First Name:");
console.log("Hi" + firstName);
```

"Expected Output: Hi Ifeoluwa"

"Actual result: Undefined and node exits automatically"

[Node Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68HTj.jpg)

Comment: Seems like it may be an issue between the library and node's REPL. If you run it from a file, it will work

Comment: Create a new folder. 
Run `npm init`, and select all your options.
Run `npm install --save readline-sync`.
Create a new file (say `index.js`) and paste your code in there.
Run `node index.js` or the name of your file.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera I'd try that out now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library does not work inside the REPL.

There is a line within the source code that reads:

```
  if (process.stdin.isTTY) {
    process.stdin.pause();
    try {
      fdR = fs.openSync('/dev/tty', 'r'); // device file, not process.stdin
      ttyR = process.stdin._handle;
    } catch (e) { /* ignore */ }
  }
```

The `process.stdin.pause` will stop your current REPL session. However, when run from a file, the library works well.

Comment: I tried looping an array with forEach and using readlineSync to prompt user input. But it ran just once. Help me.

`javascript
nameByLine.forEach(name => {
    let userRes = readlineSync.question("Is"+ name "in class");
    if (userRes.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
      present = name + ":\t\t✅"
      attendance.push(present);
    } else {
      absent = name + ":\t\t❌";
      attendance.push(absent);
    }
  })
`

Comment: You may want to open a new question and post all of your code.

Comment: [The question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56622772/create-an-attendance-register-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

i've read the documantion and it's working as expected, try to put the code to this [sandbox](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');

// Wait for user's response.
var userName = readlineSync.question('May I have your name? ');
console.log('Hi ' + userName + '!');

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running`);
});
```

Comment: But then do you know why it is giving me that output?

Comment: i think, your setup of nodejs project is wrong, i'll update my answer, you can try this one

Comment: The issue was between the library and node. Solved now.