# Create an attendance register with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Question:

Read student names, line by line, from a .txt file.

For each name, ask if the student is in class.

E.g: 
Is Michael in class? [yes/no]

Let the user input either yes or no.

Store each name and entry in another .txt file.

Solution:

I've written this almost working code just having problem looping through readlineSync module to prompt the names one after the other.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("./test.txt");
var nameByLine = text.toString().split("\n");
var readlineSync = require("readline-sync");
module.exports = function rollCall() {
  let attendance = [];

  nameByLine.forEach(name => {
    let userResp = readlineSync.question(`Is ${name} in class: `);
    if (userResp.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
      present = `${name}:\t\t✅}`;
      attendance.push(present);
    } else {
      absent = `${name}:\t\t❌}`;
      attendance.push(absent);
    }
  });

  attendance;
  return fs.writeFileSync("./newtest.txt", attendance.join("\n"));
};
```

Expected output: 
- Is `name[1]` in class: yes
- Is `name[2]` in class: no

Result"
- Is `name[1] name[2]` in class: yes

Before running the code

[image: Before running the code]

After running the code

[image: After running the code]

Comment: What does `console.log(nameByLine)` show?

Comment: Looks like the names you are reading in aren't separated by a newline but rather a CSV. Can you show an example of the register list file?

Comment: ["Bisi", "John", "Davis", "Kemi", "Olaoluwa"]

Comment: @James the names are separated by commas in the .txt file

Comment: @PeterAbolude therein lies the problem, `readline-sync` will read the entire string in until it it's a newline - there are no newlines in your register file. You need to put each name on a newline rather than CSV format

Comment: @James it worked. Would you mind reposting the comment as an answer for future reference and upvote. Thank You

Comment: @PeterAbolude sure

Comment: @PeterAbolude umm ok, I won't bother then as you've already accepted an answer ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are splitting the file using newline(`\n`) but the file is in CSV.

So there are two solutions:

1) Put the names in single line. The code will work as is.
2) Split the line using comma.

```
nameByLine.split(',').map((e)=>e.trim()).forEach(...)
```

Comment: Perfect. Used the second method tho